# Syncing data in pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a situation to which I can find no easy solution and I am looking for some common solutions to this issue.

I have a deployment with three pods doing simple CRUD operations with some HTTP resources. Now if first client POSTs a new resource to one of the pods and second clients posts a GET to some other pod shortly aftwerward, how can I make sure that second client gets the resource from another pod?

This resource is held abstract on purpose, as this problem can appear both with Restful and with database-stored resources ( when application internal caching is used )

Comment: This is a little bit too broad to answer, as the solution tends to be specific to the resource and the [consistency model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model) required. redis, memcache, apache ignite are common tools for caching. regular db's do replication as well.

Comment: and many cloud providers have network file systems that can be read/write shared in pods... again depends on the use case

Comment: But in any case there has to be a mechanism external to pods, which manages this communicatoon?

Comment: It's not really something kubernetes tries to solve, that's left to the application level. An IP network is probably the standard interface that is provided.  Kubernetes itself uses an etcd cluster for it's API. You can share some data via the kube-api but I wouldn't use it for an apps crud store, unless the app specifically manages kubernetes things.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to share  something if you want the pods to know it at the same time. Some options:

- [Shared volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

  - [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)
  - Shared block storage ([EBS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes.html), Google Persistent Disk, etc. depends on where you are running )
  - [Ceph](https://ceph.io/)
  - [Glusterfs](https://www.gluster.org/)
  - ...
- Cache

  - [Redis](https://redis.io/)
  - [Memcached](https://memcached.org/)
  - Another DB
- Distributed K/V Stores

  - [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/)
  - [etcd](https://etcd.io/)
  - [Consul](https://www.consul.io/)

You can run all of the above in Kubernetes or separately as long as your pods have network connectivity to these options.

✌️